# How do I make the XML Viewer web part ignore a Doctype element?

Tags: web-part, xslt, xml-viewer-web-part

I have an issue with a SharePoint 2010 xml viewer webpart and an xml feed that contains DOCTYPE.

The xml renders fine when there is no associated XSL with the webpart. When I add XSL to the webpart I receive the following error: "Failed to apply XSLT to the content". I discovered that if I remove the `<!DOCTYPE NewsML PUBLIC "+//W3C//DTD NewsML 1.0//EN" "http://www.irxml.org/dtd/NewsML_1.0.dtd">` element from the XML it will render just fine with the XSL.

Comment: I am having the same issue, i have pretty much googled out and cannot find a resolution to this. Has anyone else got a suggestion on how to resolve this?

Comment: @NicholasKing Hey I am facing the exact same problem. You say that we need to remove doctype from source XML to make it work but in my case there is no doctype defined in XML and still facing this issue. What could be the reason?

Comment: @FrankMartin check for whitespace etc. the first thing that needs to be encountered is the opening xml decleration.